# Convert cURL statement to postman to get token

Tags: curl, oauth-2.0, token, jwt, postman

I did this curl pattern in my terminal and it worked fine.

```
curl -vvv -X POST \
  -d username=ben%2Bmember@better.co \
  -d password=1234asdf \
  -d grant_type=password \
  https://dem.better.co/oauth/token
```

by worked fine, I mean it returned an access_token, token_type: bearer, and a refresh_token.
My question is how do I reproduce this in postman to get a access_token etc. This is what I put in put there:
[image]

and
[image]
however I keep getting this error: 
[image]
I didn't put anything in my header (not sure what to do there). My authorization type is OAuth 2 btw. Please help. Much thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

Error Statement says you are missing a required parameter. why don't you put username, password and grant_type in same request?